# Java Selenium FirefoxDriver ignores given Proxy settings

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am expecting browser to show Proxy value, but it reveals my actual IP. Any idea why ?

'''

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.addPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
options.addPreference("network.proxy.https", "151.253.165.70");
options.addPreference("network.proxy.https_port", 8080);
options.addPreference("network.proxy.https_remote_dns", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com");
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use either firefoxprofile or options. add SSL for the proxy which is using by Https.
 **options.addPreference("network.proxy.ssl", "151.253.165.70");
 options.addPreference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 8080);**

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.addPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
options.addPreference("network.proxy.https", "151.253.165.70");
options.addPreference("network.proxy.https_port", 8080);
options.addPreference("network.proxy.https_remote_dns", true);

options.addPreference("network.proxy.ssl", "151.253.165.70");
options.addPreference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 8080);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com");
```

if you are using profile

```
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "151.253.165.70");
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 8080);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.https", "151.253.165.70");  
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.https_port", 8080); 
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl", "151.253.165.70");
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 8080);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.https_remote_dns", true);
```